# Dispatch event from class not on display list

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I use a controller class that extends EventDispatcher to handle file upload events. When I add a file to an ArrayCollection in this class and I want to update a component elsewhere, what's the best way to do it?

Seeing that my controller class isn't on the Display List, how can I notify my component to update?

Thanks for any helpful tips!

Comment: Dispatch a CollectionChange on the ArrayCollection, and Views that are bound to it will update. http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=about_dataproviders_5.html

Comment: Why not just make the collection bindable?

Comment: @The_asMan: Thank you, why was I making this more difficult than it had to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@The_asMan: He came up with the best approach; use binding.